# Django ORM: timedelta difference in days between 2 dates

Tags: django, django-orm

[image]

I have a database table that represents expenses associated with a given product.

These expenses, given that they're daily, have a `from_date` (the date in which they started) and `to_date` (the date in which they ended). `to_date` can be null, as these expenses might still be going.

Given 2 Python `datetime`s, `start_date` and `end_date`, I need to produce in the ORM the total spent in the period for `my_product`.

```
>>> start_date
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 20, 0, 0)

>>> end_date
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 21, 0, 0)
```

In this case, the expected output should be:

```
(-104 * (days between 08/20 and 08/25)) + (-113 * (days between 08/26 and 09/21)
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
(
my_product.income_streams
    .values("product")
    .filter(type=IncomeStream.Types.DAILY_EXPENSE)
    .filter(add_to_commission_basis=True)
    .annotate(period_expenses=Case(
        When(Q(from_date__lte=start_date) & Q(to_date__lte=end_date),
 then=ExpressionWrapper( start_date - F('to_date'), output_field=IntegerField()))
    ), # Other When cases...
)
) # Sum all period_expenses results and you've got the solution
```

And this is what's giving me problems:

```
then=ExpressionWrapper( start_date - F('to_date'), output_field=IntegerField())
```

This expression always returns 0 (please note this is why I'm not even attempting to multiply by `value`: that'd be the next step).

Apparently `start_date - F('to_date')` is not the same as "give me the difference in days between these 2 dates".

You'd acomplish this in Python with `timedelta`. What's the equivalent in the ORM?

I've tried with `ExtractDay`:

```
then=ExpressionWrapper( ExtractDay(start_date - F('to_date'))
```

But I get: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception`

And also tried with `DurationField`:

```
then=ExpressionWrapper(start_date - F('to_date'), output_field=DurationField())
```

But that also returns zero: `datetime.timedelta(0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casting `start_date` into a `DateTimeField` solves the problem, and casting the difference into a `DurationField` is the next step.

So:

```
Cast(Cast(start_date, output_field=DateTimeField()) - F('to_date'), output_field=DurationField())
```

This will work fine on any databse backend, but in order to get the difference in days, you need to wrap it in `ExtractDay`, which will throw `ValueError: Extract requires native DurationField database support.` if you use SQLite.

If you're tied to SQLite and cannot use `ExtractDay`, you can use microseconds, and convert them manually to days by dividing by 86400000000

```
duration_in_microseconds=ExpressionWrapper(F('to_date') - (Cast(start_date, output_field=DateTimeField())), output_field=IntegerField())
```

Then

```
.annotate(duration_in_days=ExpressionWrapper(F('period_duration_microseconds') / 86400000000, output_field=DecimalField())
```

Comment: Hi @Saturnix. I am using mysql, I am getting error ```Extract requires native DurationField database support.``` when use ```ExtractDay```. Any idea?

Comment: Probably need to move to PostgreSQL if you need this particular function to work